# Can I run KIVY like Tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter, kivy

I wanna learn `kivy`. But on youtube, everyone run it by creating class and have to run it by `classname().run()`. I want to simplify to run kivy like `tkinter`, I always use `root=Tk()` to create and design window. Can anyone know how to use kivy like tkinter/`root=Tk()`??

Here is my code, which I always use with tkinter:

```
from tkinter import *

root=Tk()
root.title('Stackoverflow')
root.config(bg='white')
root.geometry('400x400')
Label(root,text='Welcome to This Question, Please Answer This',font='20',bg='white').place(x=30,y=170)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: IMO kivy can't be used like tkinter. They are different. But kivy grids the widgets. So in tkinter, you can use ```<widget>.grid(row, column)``` so that it acts somewhat like kivy.

Answer (score 2):

No, Kivy doesn't have the same API as tkinter and I'm not aware of anyone having written a wrapper package to expose a similar API.

Also, I would encourage you not to worry about this - it's normal that different packages have different APIs, and in general these APIs are designed to efficiently express how the toolkit should be used. It is normal to expect to learn how a new package works.

Comment: Hmm, I can understand, but as a beginner in python, It's hard to forget my first known module and learn a new module coding system(with `class`). But I will try to learn & never give up

Answer (score -1):

## Installing Kivy

```sh
python -m pip install --upgrade pip setuptools virtualenv

python -m virtualenv kivy_program

kivy_program/Scrtips/activate

source kivy_program/Scripts/activate

source kivy_program/Scripts/activate

python -m pip install kivy[base] kivy_example
```

## Code

```py
from kivy.app import App

class myapp(App):
     pass
     # Code

if __name__ == '__main__':
  window = myapp()
```

Comment: Nope, u'r still using `class` i want `root=App`/Something like this. (Cause I'm Beginner and I'm Scared/nervous )